# How to fix cracked cabinet wood fillings?

Tags: repair, kitchens, cabinets

About a year ago, I refinished our kitchen cabinets at home. Part of that process will filling in the outdated grooves on the face of the cabinet doors with wood filling (Elmer's wood filling) to make them flat / a little more modern. After sanding, filling the grooves, sanding, filling again, sanding, priming, and painting with cabinet paint. I did not seal which may have been a mistake on my part. Since then, the fillings have cracked (assuming from fully drying out and using the doors). Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Should I just paint the cracks the same color as the cabinets since the wood putty color is showing through or will that not help at all?

Comment: You wouldn't have needed to "seal", but we still don't know to what you applied the Elmer's filler. I'm trying to glean whether you have shrinkage or simply debonding. The filler may not have liked the original finish (possibly with years of oily residue remaining). That tells us whether the filler needs to be removed or just re-filled.

Answer (score 1):

If the bulk of the surface is flat, and you have smallish poorly filled grooves, a laminate sheet overlay applied with contact cement will get you to flat and bridge the smallish poorly filled grooves.

You will probably need to sand the paint for good adhesion.